KVM switch occasionally causes keyboard & mouse to not get recognized
I'm using a KVM switch to share keyboard, mouse and monitor between two machines. One is Ubuntu 22.04 and the other is Windows 7.
The switch works 90% of the time but occasionally when switching back to Ubuntu the keyboard and mouse aren't detected. The rest of the system is fine- if I press the power button, Linux detects this and issues a power-off countdown.

It's unlikely given my mouse and keyboard won't respond but is there anything I can do at the time this happens?

Is there anything I can change to prevent this happening in future? I'm not familiar with Linux logging, is there something I can look for in the system logs and post here?



You have a hardware issue with the switch. I suggest it be replaced.
